# How to knit2html with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: windows, r, utf-8, knitr

My `.Rmd` file contains multilingual text. When I load the html page produced by `knit2html` to my joomla site the multilingual text has been replaced by squares.
Do you know of a way to request a `utf-8` encoded html page, or any other way to overcome the problem?

Comment: are those characters squares in your web browser when you view the html output directly?

Comment: @Yihui No. I see something like this "ÄïêéìÞ Åëëçíéêþí."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update:

RStudio (>= 0.97.x) and knitr (>= 1.2) know how to handle the file encoding now. RStudio will pass the file encoding to the `encoding` argument of `knit()` (e.g. `knit('foo.Rmd', encoding = 'UTF-8')`). In short, upgrading RStudio and knitr will solve the problem.

Please ignore the answer below; it is no longer an appropriate solution.

---

I did it like this (using RStudio):

1. For the `.Rmd` I chose "Save with encoding" then I selected `UTF-8`
2. Before calling `knit2html()` I gave: `options(encoding = 'UTF-8')`

That did the trick

Comment: Thanks. In fact I'm doing a batch job :-)

Comment: @Yihui I can't get this to work on Windows using RStudio 0.98.945 and knitr 1.6. Is the solution broken? `options(encoding='UTF-8'); knitr::knit2html(input='report.Rmd', encoding='UTF-8')`, where the Rmd-file is stored as UTF-8. Have I forgotten something, or should I just stay away from Windows? :)

Comment: I restarted the session, and then it worked when **not** running `options(encoding='UTF-8')`.

Comment: @reinholdsson To save myself from trouble, I have decided to stick with version 0.98.507 for as long as it takes.